# Configuration for application in docker container on cluster

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

How can I deploy an application in a docker container on a cluster of machines and configure that application with settings like database username and password and other application specific settings. without putting the settings in the container as config file and without placing the settings on de machine, because the machine is recyclable. Also Environment variables are no options because these are visible in logs and not really suited for passwords and private keys imo.

The application is a Node.js application when developing I run it with a JSON config file. The production environment will exists of multiple machines in a AWS ECS environment. The machines all run docker in a cluster and the application it self is a docker image, and multiple instances of the application will run with an load balancer dividing the load between the instances.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) which is responsible for running and mannaging containers running on a cluster of machines. Docker swarm has a very nice feature for securing configuration such as passwords ... called [Docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/).

You can create docker secrets for usernames and passwords, and those secrets will be shared among the containers in the cluster in an encrypted and secure way.

Comment: Ok sorry, I forgot to mention that we use AWS and try to use ECS cluster. I will modify my original question to include this.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-secrets-for-amazon-ecs-applications-using-parameter-store-and-iam-roles-for-tasks/